# Renormalize git history

Tags: git, git-tfs

I am trying to renormalize the line endings in my git history. I would like to do this, since this repo is created from a tfs repo with git-tfs and there are multiple commits with messed up line endings.

Why wouldn't git rebase --root --strategy renormalize master correct the line endings in commits if I've already rebased a .gitattributes file into the first commit containing * text=auto ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebasing copies commits, but it has limitations.  The biggest one is that it literally *cannot* copy any merge commits.  Modern Git (within the last year or two) has acquired the `--rebase-merges` flag, which gets one closer, but it's still impossible to *copy* the merges.  So here, Git will *re-perform* merges.

This *could* be good enough—but there's still a hitch.  Even with the new initial commit having the desired `.gitattributes` in it (in which case you can just convert that commit's *contents* at the same time, and hence not need `--root`), when rebase does a commit-copy, it won't necessarily normalize the line endings of every file.  For instance, suppose we have this little mini-graph:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

You might use `git switch --orphan new-master` to get ready to create a new root commit, then read out the contents of commit `A`, add the `.gitattributes`, normalize line endings for all working tree files and their index copies, and commit, to get new commit `A'`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master

A'  <-- new-master (HEAD)
```

So far, we're in good shape.  Now we run `git cherry-pick master~1`, which is what `git rebase` will do to copy commit `B` to a new commit `B'`.  Between `A` and `B`, some file is modified, so Git copies the modifications to those files into your index and working tree and you force it to renormalize those files' line endings to handle any fixing-up required to make the changes fit.  But `B` also adds one entirely-new file whose line endings don't match up correctly.  Since this *new* file has no corresponding file in either `A` or `A'`, Git can—and I think will, although you'd have to test it to find out for sure—just copy it wholesale without renormalizing *its* line endings.

Git would repeat this for `B`-vs-`C`; again, any all-new file might not be renormalized.  So you end up with:

```
A--B--C   <-- master

A'-B'-C'  <-- new-master (HEAD)
```

in which files that were introduced since `A` might not have the right line endings in some commits.

If the copies made by rebase *are* renormalized, we're down to just the merge issues.  If you don't mind the merges being re-performed—which may require that you re-resolve any merge *conflicts*—then this overall strategy should work.

There is, however, another way to do this.  Instead of using rebase, you can use `git filter-branch` or its modern (but not yet distributed with Git) replacement, `git filter-repo`.  These are both capable of taking each original commit—*including* merges—and applying a "content filter" to each *file* in the original commit before making a new commit.

The content filter you would want would be:

- add `.gitattributes`, then
- renormalize

The filter-branch filters are not particularly good at this but you definitely *do* it (probably, the slowest filter, the `--tree-filter`, would work out of the box here: a tree filter that copies `/tmp/.gitattributes` to `./.gitattributes` might suffice).  The filter-repo command is under active development and you could request an "add attributes and renormalize" command line option, since this seems like something people want to do more these days.